# Django reverse foreign key in

Tags: django, django-models

Model:

```
class Book:
    title = CharField()
    author = ForeignKey(Person, related_name='books')

class Person:
    name = CharField()
```

How do I select persons that has books from a certain set?

For example, select all persons, that have ('A', 'B', 'C') as books (and possibly more), i.e. subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `intersection`:

```
queryset = Person.objects.filter(books__title='A').intersection(Person.objects.filter(books__title='B'), Person.objects.filter(books__title='C'))
```

If you are using Django older than 1.11 then:

```
queryset = Person.objects.filter(books__title='A') & Person.objects.filter(books__title='B') & Person.objects.filter(books__title='C')
```

Comment: What if I want exact equality?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get set of authors  of specific set of books:

```
Person.object.filter(books__in=Book.objects.filter(name__in=['A','B','C']))
```

or shorter:

```
Person.object.filter(books__name__in=['A','B','C']))
```

Comment: What if I want exact equality?

Comment: @AndrewFount What is exact equality? Just use = instead of __in

Comment: Exactly ['A', 'B', C']